# Discord.js - TypeError: client.on is not a function

Tags: node.js, discord.js, client, chatbot

I am making a chatbot but I keep getting this error:

```js
TypeError: client.on is not a function
```

**The event code:**

```js
const { chatBot } = require('reconlx');
const client = require('../app');
const Schema = require('../database/models/chatbot-channel');

client.on("message", async (message) =>{
    if(!message.guild || message.author.bot) return;
    Schema.findOne({ Guild: message.guild.id }, async(err, data) => {
        if(!data) return;
        if(message.channel.id !== data.Channel) return;
        chatBot(message, message.content, message.author.id);
    });
});
```

**The model I am using:**

```js
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

model.models = model(
    "chatbot", 
    new Schema({
        Guild: String,
        Channel: String,
    })
);
```

**The set channel command:**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Client, Message, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const Schema = require('../database/models/chatbot-channel');

module.exports = {
    name: 'set-chatbot',
    description: 'sets a channel for a chatbot!',
    devOnly: true,
    async execute(message, args, client) {
        const channel = message.mentions.channels.first() || message.channel;
        Schema.findOne({ Guild: message.guild.id }, async(err, data) => {
            if(data) data.delete();
            new Schema({
                Guild: message.guild.id,
                Channel: channel.id,
            }).save();
            message.channel.send(`Saved Chatbot Channel To ${channel}`);
        });
    },
};
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong? I don't see the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You're not creating the `client` correctly. You need to add this at the very top of your `event code`:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
```

Comment: now i do get this error:
`TypeError: Discord.client is not a constructor`

Comment: Did you lowercase `Client()` in `new Discord.Client()`? If yes then you have to capitalize the 'c'

Comment: the bot goes on but when i enter the command it says `TypeError: Schema.findOne is not a function`

Comment: Debug your program and check if `Schema` is `undefined`